# FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit’ does not contain bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Everytime trying to run that code in my Mac, it fires that error

> ‘/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MalaebappV3-booqrwdhpgaifkchtlgmmtgyayxd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MalaebappV3/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit’
> does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
> (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
> vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file
> ‘/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MalaebappV3-booqrwdhpgaifkchtlgmmtgyayxd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MalaebappV3/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit’
> for architecture arm64

That same codebase build normally on my friend Mac M1 chip

but fires that error on my Mac Intel chip